# Need to delete irrelevant rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the following code not delete irrelevant rows in my spreadsheet?

```
Sub Macro1Format() 

' 

' Macro1Format Macro 

' 

Dim i As Integer 

i = 0 

Do While (Range("A1").Value <> "Project ID") And (i < 100) 

    Range("1:1").Delete 

    i = i + 1 

Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: this does not explains the problem, you should explain what is the problem and what does this code should do

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a read through [Stack Overflow help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask questions well - in short, you need to describe your problem, say what you want to achieve and why it doesn't work as planned. Also have a look at [Editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see about formatting (you want four-space indent for any code blocks). Finally, please avoid shouting at us with an all-capital title. You may think it makes your question more noticeable. It does, but in a bad way, making people not want to answer you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take a stab that you would like something like:

```
Sub Macro1Format() 
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 99
    For i = 99 To 1 Step -1
        If Range("A" & i).Value <> "Project ID" Then
           Range(i & ":" & i).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You seem to have confused `1` with `i` but also when deleting rows it may be best to start from the bottom up since the row count changes as a consequence of any row deletion. There were also some syntax problems.